# What's wrong with this jquery if then function

Tags: jquery

Here's my function.

```
<script>
  if( $('#bla').text() > 1 ) {
    alert( "yup!" );
  }else{
    alert( "nope!" );
  }
</script>
```

I tested it out numerous times and it doesn't open the alerts. What's wrong?

Comment: Could you please create jsfiddle with it?

Comment: Does `$('#bla')` exist when the script runs?

Comment: yes it exists when the script is called.

Comment: It should work fine...http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/3fKyS/

Answer (score 2):

`($('#bla').text()>1)` is comparing a string to a number, and it will always return false.

I assume you expect #bla to be a number so you should tell javascript to parse it as such: `parseInt($("#bla").text(),10)` or `parseFloat($("#bla").text())`

ETA: 
Upon review of @elclanrs's fiddle it seems that javascript can handle the conversion just fine. There must be something else happening here. The syntax looks fine; the only thing left is that `$("#bla")` is returning an empty array...

Comment: I tought this too but it seems to work fine for me without parsing...http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/3fKyS

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify it inside a function.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
if($('#bla').text()>1){
   alert("yup!");
}else{
   alert("nope!");
}
});
</script>
```

Also post your HTML code since we need to know what exactly you are trying to parse and find out if its greater than 1. Mostly, jquery code executes before the html is parsed hence that could also be an issue why its not giving you the alerts.

Comment: Not necessarily. If the javascript comes _after_ the element on the page, then this is fine. Specify locality.